# serialize and unserialize array to file - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, serialization

I have an array that say for the example looks like that:

```
var position = [1,3,4,6];
```

I want to serialize the array to a file, let say position.txt.

Than I want to load the data saved to another running JS program, something like this:

```
var position = loadArrayFromFile("position.txt");
```

Is there something that I can use to do that?

Comment: try `JSON.stringify` on writing and `JSON.parse` or `require` on reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON and file I/O is how I'd do it:

- [`JSON.stringify`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-json.stringify) with [`writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) to write
- [`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) with [`JSON.parse`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-json.parse) to read